# SQL - Identify consecutive numbers in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to flag consecutive numbers in an SQL table?

Based on the values in 'value_group_4' column, is it possible to tag continous values? This needs to be done within groups of each 'date_group_1'

I tried using row_numbers, rank, dense_rank but unable to come up with a foolproof way.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `LAG` or `LEAD`?

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 2008, which doesn't recognize both unfortunately

Comment: You probably want to consider your upgrade path then; 2008 is about to run entirely out of support.

Comment: what is the order value that determines which rows are 'consecutive'?

Comment: @SQLRaptor, the date_group_1, value_group_3

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please provide CREATE TABLE, and INSERT statements for the sample data, so we don't have to do it for you.

Comment: As to your sample data: **(1)** For one date a lower value_group_3 also means a lower value_group_4 (e.g. for date 11-Jan 15.3 is lower than 17.3 and 0 is lower than 1). Is this always the case? **(2)** When there is a duplicate value_group_4 for a date, the value_group_3 is also a duplicate (e.g. both rows that have value_group_4 = 1 for 11-Jan also have value_group_3 = 17.3). Is this always the case?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with consecutiveness. You simply want to mark all rows where date_group_1 and value_group_4 are not unique.

One way:

```
select
  mytable.*,
  case when exists
  (
    select null
    from mytable agg
    where agg.date_group_1 = mytable.date_group_1
    and agg.value_group_4 = mytable.value_group_4
    group by agg.date_group_1, agg.value_group_4
    having count(*) > 1
  ) then 1 else 0 end as flag
from mytable
order by date_group_1, value_group_4;
```

In a later version of SQL Server you'd use `COUNT OVER` instead.

Comment: does CASE WHEN work that way? to compare composite values?

Comment: If I understand the OP question, this has everything to do with consecutiveness, since if the first row had 1 for value_group_4 instead of the second row in the sample data, he doesn't consider them 'continuous'. Also, SQL Server doesn't support value list for IN, only scalars.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't remember that SQL Server didn't support tuples as the other common DBMS do. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @SQLRaptor: You may be right about consecutiveness. I wrote my answer before tempidope mentioned an order by value_group_3, rather than value_group_4. The sample data doesn't help much, because the orders of value_group_3 and value_group_4 are correlated and wherever we find the same value_group_4 we also see the same value_group_3.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQL Server doesn't have a full suite of windowing functions it should be still possible. This problem looks like a last-non-null problem which Itzik Ben-Gan has good example here... http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/last-non-null-puzzle

Also, look at Mikael Eriksson's answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208935/how-to-select-the-set-of-last-non-null-values-per-column-over-a-group) which uses no windowing functions.

Comment: Thorsten's answer is simpler, just identify the duplicates in a CTE and re-join back to original data to pull the "consecutive" rows out.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as consecutive values, unless a column specifies the ordering.  Your data does not have such an obvious column, but I'll assume one exists and just call it `id` for convenience.

With such a column, `lag()`/`lead()` does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(value_group_4) over (partition by data_group1 order by id) = value_group_4
             then 1
             when lead(value_group_4) over (partition by data_group1 order by id) = value_group_4
             then 1
             else 0
         end) as flag
from t;
```

On close inspection, `value_group_3` may do what you want.  So you can use that for the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of your data is determined by the `date_group_1`, `value_group_3` column values, then why not make it as simple as the following query:

```
select
  *,
  rank() over(partition by date_group_1 order by value_group_3) - 1 value_group_3,
  case
    when count(*) over(partition by date_group_1, value_group_3) > 1 then 1
    else 0
  end expected_result
from data;
```

**Output:**

```
| date_group_1 | category_group_2 | value_group_3 | value_group_3 | expected_result |
+--------------+------------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 2018-01-11   | A                | 15.3          |             0 |               0 |
| 2018-01-11   | B                | 17.3          |             1 |               1 |
| 2018-01-11   | A                | 17.3          |             1 |               1 |
| 2018-01-11   | B                | 21            |             3 |               0 |
| 2018-01-22   | A                | 15.3          |             0 |               0 |
| 2018-01-22   | B                | 17.3          |             1 |               0 |
| 2018-01-22   | A                | 21            |             2 |               0 |
| 2018-01-22   | B                | 23            |             3 |               0 |
| 2018-03-13   | A                | 15.3          |             0 |               0 |
| 2018-03-13   | B                | 17.3          |             1 |               1 |
| 2018-03-13   | A                | 17.3          |             1 |               1 |
| 2018-03-13   | B                | 23            |             3 |               0 |
| 2018-05-15   | A                | 6             |             0 |               0 |
| 2018-05-15   | B                | 6.3           |             1 |               0 |
| 2018-05-15   | A                | 15            |             2 |               0 |
| 2018-05-15   | B                | 16.3          |             3 |               1 |
| 2018-05-15   | A                | 16.3          |             3 |               1 |
| 2018-05-15   | B                | 22            |             5 |               0 |
| 2019-05-04   | A                | 0             |             0 |               0 |
| 2019-05-04   | B                | 7             |             1 |               0 |
| 2019-05-04   | A                | 15.3          |             2 |               0 |
| 2019-05-04   | B                | 17.3          |             3 |               0 |
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e0aea/1).